# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll in c# please

Tags: c#

I'm trying to run this program and get this error all the time in con.open() please help me!!!!!!!!

```
public LinkedList<Station> getAllStation()
{
       string conString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\adi\\Documents\\RailDB.mdf\";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
       con.Open();

       string sqlString = "Select s.Id, s.Name, from Stations s;";
       SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sqlString, con);
       SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
       Station s;

       LinkedList<Station> st=new LinkedList<Station>();

       while (rdr.Read())
       {
            int id = (Int32)rdr[0];
            string name = (string)rdr[1];

            s = new Station(name, id);
            st.AddLast(s);
       }

       con.Close();
       return st;
}
```

Comment: ***WHERE*** in your code do you get that exception?? And please also provide the **complete and precise** error message(s) you're getting!!

Comment: Surround your code with `try-catch` block (`try{/*your code*/}catch(Exception ex){}`)and see what will be `ex.InnerException` while debugging.

Comment: Put rdr.Close(); before con.Close(); this MIGHT BE the issue

Comment: my error is the title and it stop where the con.open() its cannot open the sql server

Comment: Looks like your connection string is wrong. Did you check it on visual studio - server explorer window for example?

Comment: i create a datatbase.mdf and from the properties i took the connecting string

Comment: create the database in visual studio

Comment: The connection string is not the problem. The problem is the stray comma in your select statement.

Comment: Excuse me? What's unclear about this question? Read the code. Of course he could give you the line throwing the error, but come on...

Comment: @Thorsten, as you say the question is clear enough, but it should still be closed as a 'simple typogaphical error'.

Comment: @Synchro Yes, he could have found his error himself of course, but putting it on hold as *unclear* is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comma after `s.Name` in this line:

```
string sqlString = "Select s.Id, s.Name, from Stations s;";
```

It should read:

```
string sqlString = "Select s.Id, s.Name from Stations s;";
```

---

On a side note, your code is not really optimal, as it leaves many resources open until garbage collected that should be closed manually. You might want to change your code to this:

```
public LinkedList<Station> getAllStation()
{
    string conString = "...";
    LinkedList<Station> st = new LinkedList<Station>();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        con.Open();

       using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select s.Id, s.Name, from Stations s;", con))
       using (SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader())
       {
           while (rdr.Read())
           {
                int id = (Int32)rdr[0];
                string name = (string)rdr[1];

                st.Add(new Station(name, id));
           }
       }
    }
    return st;
}
```

Also, instead of hardcoding the connection string like you do, I'd suggest to use the [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to make sure you always get valid connection strings.